# Parse Tree Given Grammar

Tags: parsing, tree, grammar, parse-tree

I am given the following sentence:

```
The bird tried to escape from the strong cage.
```

And the following grammar rules:

```
s->np, vp 
np->det, n 
np->det, adjp 
adjp->adj, n 
pp->p, np 
comp->p, vp 
vp->v, pp 
vp->v, comp
```

I tried left most derivation to derive the tree and also from just doing it through bottom up analysis. Here is a simple chart I tried:

[image]

The question I have is whether it is possible to have two `S` which will lead up to the route of a single `S`

More concretely is this acceptable:

```
          s
      /      \
    s          s
  /   \      /   \
NP    VP    VP    NP
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generative grammars and has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your grammar, a prepositional phrase (`pp`) consists of a preposition (`p`) followed by a noun phrase (`np`). But your parse tree shows `pp`s consisting only of a preposition ("to" and "from"). If you do the bottom-up parse with this in mind, you should arrive at the correct answer.

To answer your direct question, your grammar does not allow `s` to consist of two `s`s; only of a noun phrase (`np`) followed by a verb phrase (`vp`).